# How to search into relation table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have two tables, first is **Category** table that has `id` and `name` columns.

Second table is **Product** that has `id`, `category_id` and `name` columns.

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

My question is how to search product's name, and it's category name in one Eloquent or DB query?

---

I tried the below code, it work for products name but when I search the category name it returns nothing.

```
$searchText = $request->input('search');
Product::query()
    ->where(function($query) use($searchText){
        if($searchText) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchText.'%')
                ->orWhere(function($query2) use($searchText) {
                    $query2->with(['category' => function($query3) use ($searchText){
                        $query3->where('name', 'like', '%'.$searchText.'%');
                    }]);
                });
        }
    })
    ->paginate(8);
```

And also, I would like to ask which is best to use this scenario Eloquent or DB?

Comment: have you checked into `whereHas/orWhereHas`?  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = Product::query()->with('category')
            ->where(function($query) use($request) {
        if ($request->input('search')) {
            $search_text = $request->input('search');
            $query->where('name', 'Like', '%' . $search_text . '%')
            ->orWhereHas('category', function ($query2)use($search_text) {
                $query2->where('name', 'Like', '%' . $search_text . '%');
            });
        }
    });

    $query1 = $query->paginate(8);
```

Hope fully it will help to you easily.

Answer (score 0):

i think you could do that using orWhereHas:

```
 $searchText = $request->input('search');
      $query=  Product::query()->with('category');

      if($searchText)
      {
          $query=$query->where('products.name','Like','%'.$searchText.'%')
              ->orWhereHas('category',function ($query)use($searchText)
              {
                  $query->where('categories.name','Like','%'.$searchText.'%');
              });
      }
      $query=$query->paginate(8);
```

you can use (DB)   and join the two table, but there are no eager loading, so the result will be just rows ...

Comment: error returned **Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.name' in 'where clause'**

Comment: you should replace categories, with the table name for model Category,
also the same for 'products' with the table name for Product model